# Search Distinct values in DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have a datatable that has a few thousand rows, there are three columns and I want to search the one specific column in the datatable to find the Distinct values.  I have tried this:

```
DataRow[] dr = datatable.Select("SELECT DISTINCT Amount ");
```

Amount is the column name that I am trying to group the values by.

The error I get is:
Syntax error: Missing operand after 'DISTINCT' operator

Thanks

Comment: You have tried it. Good. What were the results?

Comment: does the datatable come from a database? If so you are best to do this search in the database rather than in your code.

Comment: You are mentioning two different goals - one is to find distinct values of column. And another - to group values by some column. So, what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm simply trying to find the distinct values at this point

Comment: worth adding the **error** to the post as an **edit**, instead of in a comment.

Comment: @Chris, Yep it does come from a database but at this point I need do this in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  DataView view = new DataView(datatable);
  DataTable distinctAmount = view.ToTable(true, "Amount", "xxx","xxxx"...);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want the distinct values, you may try to use the `DataView.ToTable()` method:

```
var distinct = datatable.DefaultView.ToTable(true, new[] { "Amount" });
foreach (DataRow item in distinct.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item[0]);
}
```

Just adding a sample approach to group by `Amount` and the display the rows based on this grouping (assuming that there is another `OtherColumn` column in your datat table):

```
datatable.Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .GroupBy(r => r["Amount"])
    .ToList().ForEach(group =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Group {0} has the following elements", group.Key);
        group.ToList().ForEach(row =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row["OtherColumn"]);
        });
    });
```